# schema-registry service failed to start due _schemas topic

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

We have **3 kafka machines** in cluster with **3 zookeepers** servers and **3 schema-registry** services

When we start the schema-registry service on one of kafka machine we get the following from schema-registry log

```
ERROR Server died unexpectedly
Unable to subscribe to the Kafka topic _schemas backing this data store. Topic may not exist
```

Therefore schema-registry services not start,

We check the list of all topics and we see the topic - **_schemas**

So we not understand why schema service is complain about this

any ideas how to continue from this stage ?

Comment: Could you also please share your schema-registry.properties and server.properties?

Comment: Are you using SSL or any non-default settings anywhere that would make the topic fail to be read/created?

Comment: I will check this when I access the machines , I will update

Comment: just want to say , as I remember we are not using ssl , but is it the one thing that could be ? or maybe some addtional other reasons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems during schema deployment _schemas topic could not able to create  by some reason.
Could be `auto.create.topics.enable` property is false in Kafka or  might error out create table while deploying Schema.

```
Trying create topic   `_schemas` manually and restart schema registry again
```

Comment: just want to mention that when we run - kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zoo01:2181 --list , then we saw the _schemas topic

Comment: by the way we have confluent kafka , so when need to look on - auto_create_topics_enable property , in order to verifyed the value ? , on which files?

Comment: another think when I access to the kafka and do grep auto_create_topics_enable server.properties , then this parameter not defined in server.properties !

Comment: what I mean I search the - auto.create.topics.enable in server.properties  , but this parameter not defined , any way the default is true , so its enabled by default

Comment: You need to set in Confluent Kafka or deployment JSON.  "auto_create_topics_enable": false

Comment: but if auto.create.topics.enable is default true ( when this parameter not set ) , then  why we ned to set it in kafka?

Comment: I mean for now the parameter not defined in server.properties , but anyway kafka take the default - true

Comment: btw, there's no such thing as "Confluent Kafka"

Comment: @cricket_007  I see your other similar post , please advise if you can

Comment: @cricket_007 about Confluent Kafka , as you know confluent use apache kafka

Comment: @Judy Please update your question to include your properties of the broker and registry. By default, the Registry will create the _schemas topic (without having to set any auto create settings), so that isn't the fix